# Spring Security and Angular official tutorial angular portion doesn't compile

Tags: angular, spring

I've been following the [Spring Security and Angular tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#add-a-home-page) but `angular` fails to compile after this step:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Demo';
  greeting = {};
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('resource').subscribe(data => this.greeting = data);
  }
}
```

My IDE complains that `id` and `content` are `unresolved variables` in

```
<div style="text-align:center"class="container">
  <h1>
    Welcome {{title}}!
  </h1>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Id: <span>{{greeting.id}}</span></p>
    <p>Message: <span>{{greeting.content}}!</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this tutorial just out of date or am I possible doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You IDE is complaining because `greetings` is an empty object. It's normal, because it is an empty object `greeting = {};`.

If you want to avoid this warning, you can create an object with optionnals properties:

```
class Data { 
    constructor(public id?:string, public content?:string){}
}
```

and use it in your component `greeting: Data = {};`

---

You can also create an object without optionnals properties:

```
class Data { 
    constructor(public id:string, public content:string){}
}
```

and use it in your component `greeting: Data;` and in your HTML use

```
<p>Id: <span>{{greeting?.id}}</span></p>
<p>Message: <span>{{greeting?.content}}!</span></p>
```

---

You can also use `greeting: any;` but I would not recommand the use of `any` if you can type your object instead. It's much clearer to use.

---

Or just ignore the warning/suppress the warning for the sake of the tutorial only.

Comment: The tutorial has you delete that, and if you leave it in you get an error that type object isn't assignable to type string.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Would suppressing the warning make angular successfully compile?

Comment: If it's during compilation that you have this error, no, afaik, you can't supress it. I thought it was only your IDE which was showing this warning.